# AWS SNS - how should I be sending message data, MessageAttributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm building an application that enables clients to book appointments with service providers.  I'm using SNS -> SQS -> Lambda to process various emails that need to be sent when booking an appointment.  IE I currently send an SNS message like so (in node.js):

```
await sns.publish({
    Message: 'booking-request',
    TopicArn: process.env.AWS_BOOKING_REQUEST_TOPIC_ARN,
    MessageAttributes: {
      artistEmail: SNSMF.string(artist.email),
      artistName: SNSMF.string(artist.name),
      clientEmail: SNSMF.string(req.body.email),
      clientName: SNSMF.string(`${req.body.firstName} ${req.body.lastName}`),
      date: SNSMF.string(moment(req.body.date).tz(studio.timeZone).format())
    }
  }).promise();
```

This all works fine, but I'm using `MessageAttributes` to pass the pertinent appointment details so my notifications layer can send the proper emails.

My main questions is, am I using MessageAttributes in the proper way, or is there a better way to pass all of this data?  Should the data be the message itself?  I ask because I believe that you can only have 10 MessageAttributes and I'm going to run into a limit with the appointment details (currently collecting about 10-12 data points about the appointment that I want to include in the emails).  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157079/purpose-of-amazon-sqs-messages-body/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the 'main' information you wish to pass would be in the `Body` of the message. It is quite common the use JSON to pass various types of information.

`MessageAttributes` are normally something *about the message itself* rather than the *content* of the message, such as timestamps, priority and user information.

Given your requirements, I putting your data in the `Body` (eg in JSON) would avoid hitting limits and would also be more extensible.

Comment: Thans John.  I ended up doing as you suggested, and JSON.stringify(...) and then parsing it in the handling code.  Works great.  Thanks!